# JButton wont change size or position on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I added a button into JPanel and tried to change the size and the position of the button. I've tried different lines of codes but they wont work. Also putting in `parent.setLayout(null);` or `panel.setLayout(null);` will just completely remove the button and the background

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class app {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame parent = new JFrame("CPS TEST");
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        parent.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        parent.setSize(500, 300);
        parent.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        parent.setVisible(true);
        parent.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't giving us quite enough information. HOW are you attempting to change the size of the button, and when? Is there something in the code you've posted that is behaving somehow differently than you expect, and, if so, what is it? We're happy to help, but we can't write the question for you.

Comment: @arcy what im trying to say is, adding button.setSize wont change the buttons size and using button.setBounds wont change the position.

Comment: And this is still not enough information to help you. It matters where you are putting the button, whether a layout manager is involved, whether you are paying enough attention to the UI dispatch thread. I have spent a lot of time guessing what people need, and it's usually wasted. The program that you've posted, assuming it runs at all, does not illustrate the problem you describe -- there is no attempt to change the button's size there. I will also suggest that you take a step back and tell what you want to do overall instead of this call to `setSize()`. We'll still need specifics.

Comment: *tried to change the size and the position of the button* - why?  Swing components are designed to determine their own preferred size.  If you are trying to add extra space around the text, the use the `setMargin(...)` method. Layout managers will position the button based on the rules of the layout manager. If you want a different location, then use a different layout manager. You have already been asked for details of your requirement which you haven't provided, so we can't give specific suggestions. (1-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to increase the size of a button:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Changing the position of a component is worthy of a separate question, but changing the size of a button is easy.